# Booting linux from CFE

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, device-tree, broadcom

I'm trying to boot a linux image (3.14) on a powerpc processor board. I have as my boot loader broadcom's CFE boot loader. I appear to be having problems with the device tree.

When CFE branches to the kernel entry point it goes (by default) to 0x00000000 and then prints out the string:

OF-device-tree at 0x00ffc000

Can anyone tell me what part of this system is printing out that final string? I can not find it in the Linux kernel source and I don't have access to the CFE source code.

Once that string is printed out the system seems to be halted. No further output is seen.

Cheers!!